# Dockering A Yii2 API , MySQL Database and ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, docker, yii2, docker-compose

I'm quite new to the concepts of Docker and how it works. But I have developed an application that runs Mysql Db from PHPMyadmin, backend is a Yii2 API and frontend in ReactJs.

I would like to dockerize this application before I deploy it but I'm not verse with Docker just yet.

I would be grateful if anyone can just give me guiding steps on how to dockerize each of this sections into a container( ending up with 3 containers ), intercommunicate the containers and launch my application. I can't see a clear guide on all of this online.

I have started dockerizing my API using Docker Composer with a script like this.

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    image: yiisoftware/yii2-php:7.1-apache
    volumes:
      - ~/.composer-docker/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
      - ./:/app:delegated
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
  db_mysql:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'dockermysql'
```

I'm not sure of what I'm actually doing or the next steps to take.

Comment: I believe this is considered too broad for StackOverflow. At least one thing is clear from your question - you should build a Dockerfile for at least your PHP app. This Dockerfile should `COPY` your app files to the container.